# Camel - ControlBus - Activate timer route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a timer route that is initially not started.  I would like to activate it from another route.  I am attempting to use the camel's controlbus EIP pattern.

```
// From my other route
.to("controlbus:route?routeId=fileConsumerRoute&action=start&async=true")

from("timer://camel-fileConsumerRoute?fixedRate=true&period=5s")
    .routeId("fileConsumerRoute").noAutoStartup()
    .log("Route is running");
```

I see in the logs aft the controlbus line is run that the route is being resumed

> Context action: [resume]

but the timer still does not fire. I dont see the log line "Route is running"

How do I activate the timer endpoint with the controlbus?

Is there another EIP pattern or diffrent way to achieve activating the timer endpoint?

Comment: Works fine with Camel 2.23.1 - https://gist.github.com/bedlaj/3753d1f9ec5b3f4ee6aae0fea1295126 . Which Camel version are you using?

Comment: I tried your test-case and I see that it passes.  I looked back at my code .. and I see I was using resume, on the route which was set to .noAutoStartup().  If the route is not started, you must use 'start' prior to 'resume'.

Your test case helped me very much - thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm late to the party, but, you could use controlbus or something like this start stop routes. if there is some predicate some other boolean test.

example:

we test if some condition exists every period and perform operation on result of condition...

```
<!-- Token Database -->
<route autoStartup="true" id="core.predix.tkndependencyCheckerRoute">
    <from id="_from2" uri="timer://tkndbAvailable?fixedRate=true&amp;period=30000"/>
    <process id="_process2" ref="tkndbAvailableProcessor"/>
</route>

public class TknDbAvailableProcessor implements Processor {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TknDbAvailableProcessor.class);

    private TKNDataService tknDataService = null;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        ServiceStatus status = exchange.getContext().getRouteStatus("core.fleet.EnrichmentRoute");  

        if (null == tknDataService) {

            if (status.isStarted()) {
                exchange.getContext().stopRoute("core.fleet.EnrichmentRoute");  
            }           
        } else {

            if (tknDataService.isTKNDataServiceAvailable()) {

                if (status.isStopped()) {
                    exchange.getContext().startRoute("core.fleet.EnrichmentRoute");  
                }
            } else {

                if (status.isStarted()) {
                    exchange.getContext().stopRoute("core.fleet.EnrichmentRoute");  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setDataService(TKNDataService dataService) {
        this.tknDataService = dataService;
    }

}
```

---

If needing a master singleton route if needing redundancy - on diff nodes use a JGroups Cluster with ControlBus

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jgroups.JGroupsFilters"
    factory-method="dropNonCoordinatorViews"
    id="dropNonCoordinatorViews" scope="prototype"/>
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jgroups.JGroupsExpressions"
    factory-method="delayIfContextNotStarted"
    id="delayIfContextNotStarted" scope="prototype">
    <argument value="5000"/>
</bean>

<route autoStartup="true" id="FleetMainClusterControlRoute">
    <from id="_from2" uri="jgroups:mainCluster?enableViewMessages=true&amp;channelProperties=etc/jgroups.xml"/>
    <filter id="filterNonCoordinatorViews">
        <method ref="dropNonCoordinatorViews"/>
        <threads id="threads1" threadName="ControlThreads">
            <delay id="_delay1">
                <ref>delayIfContextNotStarted</ref>
                <log id="logCR" loggingLevel="INFO" message="Starting Main Cluster consumer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"/>
                <to id="_toCR" uri="controlbus:route?routeId=core.predix.tkndependencyCheckerRoute&amp;action=start&amp;async=true"/>
            </delay>
        </threads>
    </filter>
</route>
```